# Re-open a script in ruby

Tags: ruby, scripting

I would like to re-open my script at the end of its execution. I tried with load but it didn't work. Is what I want to do possible? If yes, what should I try?

This is the structure of my script:

```
usr_choice = gets.chomp.to_i 
case usr_choice 
  when 1 
   # Do something
  when 2 
   # Do something else
  else 
   puts "Choice not recognised"
end
```

Basically I would like for example to go back to the user input (`usr_choice`) after going through the `case` statement. Without a GoTo.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? could you not just put you code in a function and then create some logic in order to loop that logic?

Comment: what do you mean by "re-open"?

Comment: When I said re-open I meant to say that I would like to open the same script at the end of its execution. Because I have a user input at the beginning and I would like the user to have the choice to do something else. Do you know what I mean? I know that it's not super clear ...

Comment: @JeremyL. can you show some code?

Comment: Sure! Here is an extract:

usr_choice = gets.chomp.to_i
case usr_choice
when 1
when 2
else
end

Basically I would like for example to go back to the user input (usr_choice) after going through the "case" statement. Without a GoTo.

Comment: So if the user chooses "1" or even "2" then the script starts over and asks the user for their choice again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a loop? Well, use `loop`:

```
loop do
  usr_choice = gets.chomp.to_i

  case usr_choice
  when 1
    puts 'one'
  when 2 
    puts 'two'
  else
    break # exit the loop (not the case construct as in other languages)
  end
end
```

Example:

```
$ ruby filename.rb
1
one
2
two
1
one
kthxbye
$
```